# How can i wait for Ajax GET call response from Node.js and then return true for the droppable to accept dropping?

Tags: node.js, jquery-ui

I have a node server that is running on different port "81", i want to get the response for the Ajax GET call then check the response if it has some kind value return true for `accept` attribute for `droppable` callback function.

This is the code i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.user').draggable();
    $('.user').droppable({

      accept: function() {

      $.ajax("http://127.0.0.1:81/").done(function(data){
          if(data.toString() == "success")
             return true;
          else
             return false
               });        
            }, 
             activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
             hoverClass:  'ui-state-active'
             drop: function(event, ui){
                  $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("b").html("User deleted.");       
                }

    });

});
```

});

And how can i get the response from data.
Note: In the Node.js server i'm returning a text with `res.end("success");`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Express js, you problem will be solved. for example use the below code

```
res.send({"status":"success"})
```

or

```
res.json({status:"success"});
```

try like this will work